# What happens to the mean terms when solving regression coefficients using covariance?

Tags: regression, least-squares, covariance, matrix

Assuming $X$ is a full-rank $n \times p$ design matrix, and $y$ is an $n$ vector,
it is possible to solve the regression coefficient vector $\hat{\beta}$ using either $\hat{\beta}=(X^T X)^{-1} X^T y$ ie the OLS method, or by calculating the covariance matricies $S_{XX}$ and $S_{Xy}$, and then $\hat{\beta} = S_{XX}^{-1} S_{Xy}$.

I would like to prove that both expressions are equivalent to each other. The step I can do is expand the sample covariance terms to:

$$\begin{aligned}
\hat{\beta} &= S_{XX}^{-1} S_{Xy}\\
&= \left( \frac{1}{n-1} X^TX - \bar{X}^T\bar{X} \right)^{-1}  \left( \frac{1}{n-1} X^Ty - \bar{X}^T\bar{y} \right)\\
&=\left( X^TX - \bar{X}^T\bar{X} \right)^{-1}  \left(  X^Ty - \bar{X}^T\bar{y} \right)
\end{aligned}$$

Where I'm stuck is proving that these mean terms $\bar{X}^T\bar{X}$ and $\bar{X}^T\bar{y}$ cancel out to result in the above expression for the OLS coefficients. How can this be done?

Comment: What does it mean to calculate the covariance between $X$ and $y?$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-covariance_matrix

Comment: Although we are dealing with empirical covariances in this case

Comment: What are $\bar X \bar X$ and $\bar X \bar y?$ Are these supposed to be vectors? Scalars? Matrices?

Comment: These are sample means. Y bar is a scalar and X bar is a p vector

Comment: So then what is $\bar X \bar X?$ In other words, let $\bar X = (1, 2)^T$. What is $\bar X \bar X?$

Comment: Oh whoops I forgot the transpose there

Comment: The duplicate--which we have discussed in comments there--gives a perfectly rigorous mathematical demonstration.  Another approach is to write, in matrix form, the Gaussian elimination steps described there.  This leads to an easily proven identity.

Comment: I disagree, it uses a computational argument when I am after a symbolic, logical one. This Gaussian elimination argument is comparable to just showing me the results from both methods in R and telling me they are the same.

Comment: Nothing about that argument requires any reference to software.  As I pointed out in the preceding comment, all you are asking is to express the *same* argument in matrix notation.  The answer is no different.